# Ionic 4 Not support Events?

Tags: ionic4

Im using Event fucntion to publish some data in app. But its not working in ionic 4. I need to know ionic 4 support Events or not?

```js
import { Events } from '@ionic-angular';
// Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@ionic-angular'
```

Comment: Typo @ionic/angular

Comment: yeah looks like Events are not supported in v4. At least official docs do not mention it;/

Comment: Go through migration docs. Its supported but package name has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below solution is working in ionic v4

```js
import { Events } from '@ionic/angular';

constructor(private events: Events) {
    events.subscribe('notificationLength', notilen => {
    //TO DO`enter code here`
    })
}

// Publish the events where ever you want
this.events.publish('notificationLength', this.NotificationList.length)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `@angular/Events`

```js
//MyEvents Service Page

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EventsService {

    constructor() { }

    private subject = new Subject<any>();

    sendMessage(text){
    this.subject.next(text);
    }

    getMessage():Observable<any>{
    return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

```js
//Page for sendMessage

constructor(private events: EventsService) {
    this.events.sendMessage({'created':1}); //send message key-value format
}
```

```js
//Page for getMessage

subscription: Subscription;

constructor(private events: EventsService) { 
    this.subscription = this.events.getMessage().subscribe(text => {
        console.log(text.created);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the version. When I updated to the latest patch of version 4, it was working.

```
npm i @ionic/angular@4.11.10
```